# inline CSS not being overridden by !important in external CSS

Tags: css

I am trying to make [this site](http://masterwindowcleaners.com.au/) responsive.

I have added the following CSS to the Wordpress theme's `custom.css`:

```css
li#vfb-3 {
    color: #808080;
}

p#form_success, .vfb-form-success {
    color: #CCFFCC;
}

#menu {
    background-image: none;
    background: #ffffff;
/* Old browsers */
/* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,#ffffff 0%,#e6e6e6 100%);
/* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color-stop(0%,#ffffff),color-stop(100%,#e6e6e6));
/* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#ffffff 0%,#e6e6e6 100%);
/* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,#ffffff 0%,#e6e6e6 100%);
/* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,#ffffff 0%,#e6e6e6 100%);
/* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,#ffffff 0%,#e6e6e6 100%);
/* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffff',endColorstr='#e6e6e6',GradientType=0);
/* IE6-8 */
}

@media (max-width:959px) {
    .container, #menu, #featured, #slides, .slide .overlay, .slide .overlay2 {
        width: 100% !important;
    }

    #featured {
        height: auto !important;
    }

    #header {
        height: 168px;
    }

    img {
        max-width: 100% !important;
        height: auto;
    }

    #menu {
        height: auto;
    }
}

@media (max-width:461px) {
    .container, #menu, #featured, #slides, .slide .overlay, .slide .overlay2 {
        width: 100%;
    }

    #featured {
        height: auto !important;
    }

    #header {
        height: 202px;
    }

    img {
        max-width: 100% !important;
        height: auto;
    }

    #menu {
        height: auto;
    }
}

@media (max-width:337px) {
    .container, #menu, #featured, #slides, .slide .overlay, .slide .overlay2 {
        width: 100%;
    }

    #featured {
        height: auto !important;
    }

    #header {
        height: 236px;
    }

    img {
        max-width: 100% !important;
        height: auto;
    }

    #menu {
        height: auto;
    }
}
```

The image slider contains a `#slides` element, which is produced by:

```
<div id="slides" style="background-image: none; width: 960px; height: 447px;">
```

However, my CSS of `#slides {width: 100% !important;}` is not being applied, when I reduce the browser width to less than 960 pixels.

Why does this happen? Thanks.

Comment: At least for me it is normal

Comment: Your code should work fine. Did you check rules applied in the element inspector?

Comment: Would be nice if you said what browser you are having this problem with.

Comment: Are the other rules you expect to be applied being applied? Did you try `@media screen and...`?

Comment: Probably the inline style is added by javascript after css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This image slider is generated by the Wordpress theme.

I replaced it with a dedicated slider plugin, and the issue went away, because the dedicated plugin had responsiveness built into it.

Answer (score 0):

your structure is somewhat like code below -

```
<div id="slides"></div>
  <div class="slide" style="width:960px;...*other styles*">
    *tags within*
  </div>
  <div class="slide" style="width:960px;...*other styles*">
    *tags within*
  </div>
  <div class="slide" style="width:960px;...*other styles*">
    *tags within*
  </div>
  <div class="slide" style="width:960px;...*other styles*">
    *tags within*
  </div>
</div>
```

Now even though **#slides** takes width as 100% when screen size is smaller than 960px, its children **.slide** take up with of 960px and so does the image tag within .slides.
You must override **.slides** and **img** as well to width: 100% as -

```
@media (max-width:959px) {
  #slides > .slide, #slides img {
    width: 100% !important;
  }
}
```